# React router redirect outside of route component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I use React Router in my React application.
In Header component that isn't inside Router component i want to redirect user after register a form, but because Header component is outside of Router component i can't use `this.props.history.push('/');`.
How can i redirect user in Header component?
This is my App component:

```
<div>
    <Header order={this.order}/>
    <Router data={this.state.data}>
      <div>
        <Menu data={this.state.data}/>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/post" component={PostList} />
        <Route path="/showpost/:slug" component={ShowPost} />
        <Route path="/page/:slug" component={ShowPage} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route path="/forgotpassword" component={Forgot} />
        <Route path="/password/reset/:token" component={Reset} />
        <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
        <Route path="/user" component={User} />
        <Route path="/saveorder" render={()=><SaveOrder data={this.state.data}/>} />
      </div>
    </Router>
    <Map />
    <Footer />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `this.props.history.push('/')` if your Header component is passed to the withRouter HOC.
withRouter allows you to get history in component props.

So... in Header component you should import withRouter HOC

`import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';`

and export your Header component like this:

`export default withRouter(Header);`

You can find more info about programmatic navigation here https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/

an example of what you want to do is found at the end of the post :)

Comment: I get error "You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>"

Comment: You should then place Header inside Router just like @AmineHakkou said. Or use a container component containing your route as a child. [Check out this gist](https://gist.github.com/cbh6/47c337fa865729268bc535c905820544). This way your header will also be inside router so you can access history

Answer (score 0):

move Header inside `Router`, only the component that are inside `<Router>` that can use any of react-router's apis.

the code would look like this:

```
  <div>
    <Router data={this.state.data}>
      <div>
        <Header order={this.order} />
        <Menu data={this.state.data} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/post" component={PostList} />
        <Route path="/showpost/:slug" component={ShowPost} />
        <Route path="/page/:slug" component={ShowPage} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route path="/forgotpassword" component={Forgot} />
        <Route path="/password/reset/:token" component={Reset} />
        <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
        <Route path="/user" component={User} />
        <Route
          path="/saveorder"
          render={() => <SaveOrder data={this.state.data} />}
        />
      </div>
    </Router>
    <Map />
    <Footer />
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't want to change header and footer on every router url change so i exclude it from Router component

Comment: It won't change as long as you tell it not to, by implementing shouldComponentUpdate()

Comment: Can you give me more hint about how to implement shouldComponentUpdate(). It means if user click on any link i can chose which component should re-render?

Comment: React-router is smart enough to do that, and considering that you moved Header outside of Router was because you didn't want the header to change on every click, it won't aslong as shouldComponentUpdate returns false, for more details see this page https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate